# I cannot properly configure location directive on nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration, webserver

I'm learning nginx configuration and I found a problem I cannot solve.
I had my server context like this in my nginx.conf file.

```
server {
        listen 192.168.1.20:80;
        server_name www.a.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/a/;
        location = /extra {
                index default.html;
        }
        location = /prova {
                index index.html;
        }
}
```

My hosts file for local DNS is

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.1.19    www.linuxhelp2.com
127.0.0.1    tech.com
192.168.1.20 www.a.com 
192.168.1.19 www.b.com
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Now I'm expecting that when I just type [www.a.com](http://www.a.com), I get an 404 error, while if I'm typing [www.a.com/prova](http://www.a.com/prova) or [www.a.com/extra](http://www.a.com/extra) I'm going to get the index directive html page. But when I type [www.a.com](http://www.a.com) I get the index.html page, while the [www.a.com/extra](http://www.a.com/extra) and [www.a.com/prova](http://www.a.com/prova) both get a 404 error.
Both index.html that default.html are in the /usr/share/nginx/html/a/ folder.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I'm expecting that when I just type [www.a.com](http://www.a.com), I get an 404 error,

The URI `/` will not match any of your `location` definitions, so Nginx will use the statements in the `server` block to process the request. The default value for `index` is `/index.html` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index)) and combined with your `root` statement causes Nginx to return the file at `/usr/share/nginx/html/a/index.html`.

> while if I'm typing [www.a.com/prova](http://www.a.com/prova) or [www.a.com/extra](http://www.a.com/extra) I'm going to get the index directive html page.

The URI `/prova` will be processed by the matching `location` block. The `index` directive is irrelevant, as the URI does not end with a `/`. Nginx will look for a file or directory by concatenating the value of the `root` with the URI, so: `/usr/share/nginx/html/a/prova` which does not exist and therefore a 404 status is returned.

---

If you want Nginx to return a specific file, you should use `try_files` instead. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

For example:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html/a;

location = /extra {
    try_files /default.html =404;
}
location = /prova {
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

Comment: Ok I get it thank you, I was totaly misunderstanding the location directive. Now everything is clear.